# Problems with setting up ActiveMQ on Tomcat with Flex, BlazeDS

Tags: flex4, tomcat7, blazeds

As i have seen on one of forums, i'm "tomcat idiot". And, unfortunately, BlazeDS, ActiveMQ idiot too :(
  I have big project, built with Tomcat, Flex 4, BlazeDS and Spring. Oracle is our database. As IDE we're using IntelliJ Idea 10.5.
  At this time i'm trying to add messaging (JMS) to our project. I chose ActiveMQ as JMS provider for our system.
  First of all, i tried to set up ActiveMQ for starting as standalone application (manual running of activemq.bat). For example of set-up, i used [article of M.Martin](http://mmartinsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/05/simplified-blazeds-and-jms.html)

Than I tried to analyze problems and used ActiveMQ help about ActiveMQ and Tomcat tuning.

But nothing helped to me. After running our web app, i've got this error from flex:
**[MessagingError message='Destination "message-destination" either does not exist or the destination has no channels defined (and the application does not define any default channels.)']**
I can post here config files, that i've got as the result of my trainings.
I loaded them on free file hosting [here](http://www.4shared.com/get/OZUIsOGo/cfg_files.html)

Comment: Same file in ZIP format - here: http://www.4shared.com/zip/V8OhL1zJ/cfg_files.html

Comment: If I can add any additional info - please, tell me.

Comment: I've got BlazeDS turnkey with ActiveMQ installed. In other side, i found text about installing ActiveMQ on Tomcat on SourceForge [BlazeDS wiki](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/blazeds/wiki/BlazeDS%204.0%20Installation%20Guide/). Example from turnkey is working, but when i move step-by-step on official document - i can't get working sample! After all, i searched config files in turnkey for keywords from off.document (i.e. <transportConnectors>, activemq.xml, etc) - and i didn't find them! How i can make working project on such "high-level" docs???